C++ program is blocked at file open
If a file is being used or locked by another process, my own program may not be able to open it. If I use the std::ifstream class in C++ to open the file, the open function returns, but the is_open function can be used to check whether the file was opened successfully.
However: I have a problem that one of my programs very rarely - 4-5 times a week - gets blocked when opening the file. That is, the open function does not return. I have a memory dump that I loaded with Visual Studio, it says that something is locked - something in an other thread -. Is this normal operation? Is it possible that my application could have corrupted some internal C++ data structure due to bad memory addressing? What can cause such an error?

I think what I'd like to see is that memory dump that says something is locked. The other issue that needs clarifying is whether your app is multi-threaded or not.

You antivirus can cause this.

something in an other thread Are you opening the same file in multiple threads?

1.: Yes, it is a multithreaded app.
2.: The tester who reported this bug disabled the antivirus program when he used this app.
3.: I wrote a simple test / demo program. I found that the file opening is thread-safe, i.e. when I opened a file in thread A, I could not open it in thread B, moreover, the open function returned and not blocked.
